# Beamer - customising the Frankfurt theme

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I use `beamer` together with `\usetheme{Frankfurt}`.
My slides look like this:

[image]

Is that possible to change the color of the bullet in the header?

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\useinnertheme{default}
\useoutertheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}       
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=white, fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=white, fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=white}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\stepcounter{subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide 2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Which color do you want to change exactly? Only the circles? Only the section title? Both? Only those in the current section? Subsection? Other (sub-)section? If you want to change the color of the whole head, you can use `\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=<foreground>, bg=<background>}` as you did in your example. If you want to change the color of only a part of the head, I guess we need to patch a few `mini frames` templates. By the way, the theme `Frankfurt` calls internally a set of inner, outer and color theme. Is this intentionally?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I'd like to change the color of the current bullet only. By default, the current bullet is filled with black. I'd like it to be... red, say. I do not get your last question regarding the inner, outer, and color themes... Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the PGF code that is used to draw the circle. The filled circle is drawn in the `beamer` template `mini frame`.

By adding

```
\pgfsetcolor{<color>}
```

or

```
\pgfsetfillcolor{<color>}
```

to the PGF picture code one can set the `<color>` to be used for the whole circle or only the filling. (There’s also `\pgfsetstrokecolor`.)

I have used an additional color `bullet` that is let to `red`.

The starred version of `\defbeamertemplate` also activated the defined template so the second argument (`Frankfurt`) can be anything (except `default`).

I’m sure one can exploit all the possibilities a `beamer` template offers after reading  the section 16.3 “Changing the Templates Used for Different Elements of a Presentation” of the [`beamer` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/beamer) …

---

The Frankfurt theme loads internally

```
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}
```

I do not see the point of additionally loading the default inner, outer and color theme.
The output does not change anyway.

### Code

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=white, fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=white, fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=white}
\colorlet{bullet}{red}
\defbeamertemplate*{mini frame}{Frankfurt}
{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}
%    \pgfsetcolor{bullet}% draw and fill in red
    \pgfsetfillcolor{bullet}% only fill in red
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0.05cm}{0.05cm}}{0.05cm}
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
[action]
{ \setbeamersize{mini frame size=.14cm,mini frame offset=.03cm} }

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\stepcounter{subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide 2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]